# friend class declaration and using directive

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend, using-directives, name-lookup

Is the following example well-formed?

```
namespace N {
    class A;
}
using namespace N;

class B {
    int i;
    friend class A;
};

namespace N {
    class A {
        B m;
        int get() { return m.i; }
    };
}
```

This example compiled successfully with Clang 3.5, but failed with g++ 4.8.1 with the following:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘int N::A::get()’:
main.cpp:7:9: error: ‘int B::i’ is private
     int i;
         ^
main.cpp:14:30: error: within this context
         int get() { return m.i; }
                              ^
```

C++11 standard §7.3.1.2 p3 says,

> If the name in a `friend` declaration is neither qualified nor a *template-id* and the declaration is a function or an *elaborated-type-specifier*, the lookup to determine whether the entity has been previously declared shall not consider any scopes outside the innermost enclosing namespace.

In example, `class A` is not member of **innermost enclosing namespace** (i.e. global namespace), but `class A` is introduced by using directive into global namespace.

Comment: Your are creating a nested namespace `N` inside N due to the `using namespace N`, try removing the last `namespace N`

Comment: @ichramm `using namespace N` doesn't mean everything that follows implicitly belongs to `namespace N`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit @Praetorian I wasn't sure until I tested the above code commenting out the last `namespace N', it's weird, I know.

Comment: @ichramm: It's not just weird: it's untrue. You're observing something else.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think you were on the right track. The code is valid, but it's not N::A that gets friend benefits. It's a not-yet-existing ::A. That's why it doesn't compile with `get()`. (IMO....)

Comment: @ichramm Your experiment is admirable, your conclusion less so.

Comment: @jrok: I think that was my conclusion too. But I was bored of see-sawing :(

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, another interesting think is that changing the friend statement with `friend class N::A` seems to fix the problem too.

Comment: Interesting note: `using N::A;` instead of `using namespace N;` compiles just fine. I'm willing to classify this as a bug.

Comment: And plain `friend A;` also compiles.

Comment: [namespace.udir]/2 "During unqualified name lookup, the names appear
as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the *using-directive* and the
nominated namespace." And [basic.lookup.elab]/2 "If the *elaborated-type-specifier* has no *nested-name-specifier*, and unless the *elaborated-type-specifier* appears
in a declaration with the following form:
*class-key attribute-specifier-seq opt identifier* `;`
the identifier is looked up according to 3.4.1 [unqualified name lookup] but ignoring any non-type names that have been declared."

Comment: I think the quoted §7.3.1.2 p3 only states that namespaces enclosing the innermost one are not searched. But the using-directive lets name lookup find the names as if they were declared in the innermost enclosing namespace (here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using namespace N is pulling the name N::A into the global namespace, it is not declaring that A in the global namespace. Hence an additional A in the global namespace is the friend of B. clang is wrong.

Comment: @Diether C++11 standard 7.3.4 p2 says "During unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), the names appear **as if** they were declared ...", and 3.4.1 p2 says "For the purpose of the unqualified name lookup rules described in 3.4.1, the declarations from the namespace nominated by the *using-directive* **are considered members of that enclosing namespace**".

Comment: @Diether: Thanks! You are very right! I found issue [N1229](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2000/n1229.html). However, I think that C++11 standard should show this situation more clearly.

Answer (score 9):

To make `N::A` without qualification a `friend` of `B` you'd use

```
friend A;
```

rather than

```
friend class A;
```

When using an elaborated type specifier, i.e., `class A`, and it is in this specific form, it introduces a class name (see 3.4.4 [basic.lookup.elab] paragraph 2).

Comment: The form mentioned in [basic.lookup.elab]/2 does not contain the `friend` as far as I can see. So the form mentioned there is a part of the friend-declaration. Does it still apply?

Comment: @dyp: yes, I'm aware. However `friend class A;` _does_ match the expression ".* _class-key attribute-specifier-seq? identifier;_". I think the intent is to distinguish it from uses like `class foo f();` or `int stat(struct stat*)`, etc. and I think it does apply.